# is it possible to make MySQL Db to store data in Uppercase without UPPER() function

Tags: mysql

I was looking to make the data in my MySQL table to be UPPERCASE no matter what case was used as input. Going through some docs and online contents I found the `UPPER()` function which will convert the data to UPPERCASE. But I want to know if there is any default option in MySQL which can convert the data to UPPERCASE without using `UPPER()` function.

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES('ironman') WHERE id=1;
```

**The MySQL DB should look like this:**

```
id name 
1  IRONMAN
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use upper function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER table_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON table
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           NEW.name = UPPER(name);
       END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```